# sql query phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Database phplogin > users

```
id                   int 11
username         varchar25
password         varchar25
```

Whats the code to add 2 users 1 named Admin and pass: 123 other named: acc2 pass: pass2

Comment: This is not a place to cheat on your exam; also, plaintext password is a *horrible* idea (as is choosing an admin password from the list of 100 most common passwords).

Comment: Are you trying to insert two users, Admin and acc2, into the table?

Comment: Also the SHA1 hash has 28 Characters, so varchar25 isn't possible..

Comment: ANyone have a link to a good php login tut?

Comment: Just google it dude, http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RUN these queries sequence wise

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);

ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT


INSERT INTO `users`(`username`,`password`) value('Admin','123'),('acc2','pass2');
```

OR(for security use sha1() to secure your password)

```
   INSERT INTO `users`(`username`,`password`) value('Admin',sha1('123')),('acc2',sha1('pass2'));
```

Comment: #1364 - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: add increment on id and make it primary